# The best way to make the view, a read-only of routeroutlet 's sections in angular ts

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to make the mid-section to be read only and just enabling the button "OPEN".

I have the below original code. "router-outlet" renders the combination of several feature components. And I do not want to disable each and every elements or feature components

```
<div="row mid-section">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <button class="btn btn-default"> OPEN </button>
</div>
```

I tried by adding as below:

```
<div="row mid-section" readonly="readonly">
```

But it still allows to edit and click on button inside mid-section div.

I would really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML `readonly` property doesn't work like that.  Its only for form fields and must be on that actual DOM element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly

Without seeing more of your code, I can't really give a better answer than these 2 options.

Option 1, a shared service that has that read only property.  You could have a service, that has a behavior subject that you can update from the parent component. The inner components would all need to have that service injected, and do something appropriate when the value changes.

Option 2, you would need a container component that has a new boolean input, and it would need to pass that value down to all the children components (which would also need an input).

Comment: I found the answer. It is on the backend we need to configure according to the architecture. It depends on the code if we have set up with table driven value or any.